# Update the preferredMaxLayoutWidth for a multiline UILabel with unknown size (Auto Layout)

Tags: ios, ios6, uilabel, autolayout

I have a custom view class which inherits from `UIView`. This class has an `UILabel` as its subview. In the `init`-function of this custom view class I set up everything needed like this:

```
//h-file
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyCustomView : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *myLabel;

@end

//m-file
@implementation MyCustomView

@synthesize myLabel = _myLabel;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        _myLabel = [UILabel new];

        if(_textView){
            _myLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            _myLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            _myLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
            _myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
            _myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [self addSubview:_myLabel];
        }
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

I also set up a bunch of constraints to manage padding inside my custom view - furthermore there are constraints to layout multiple `MyCustomView`-instances for both vertical and horizontal axis as well.

To get a multilined label output I have to set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`-property of the `UILabel` `myLabel`. The width depends on the free space available. At http://www.objc.io/issue-3/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox.html I read, that I can let Auto Layout calculate the width first and set it as `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` after the frame of the `MyCustomView`-instance (the label inside is single lined at this moment) has been set.

If I put the following function into the `MyCustomView`, the label still has a single line of text:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    float width = _myLabel.frame.size.width;
    _myLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = width;
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

If I set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to an explicit value inside the `init`-function, the label is multilined.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all the constrains you have setup for your custom view, and the superview that contains it, it's really hard to determine the problem, I suggest you to print out all the view frames of the entire view hierarchy starting from the view controller's view at viewDidLayoutSubviews and determine if the label and its superviews have correct frame set.

I have an encountered similar issues with dynamic label size and scroll view so I created a prototype here, might be useful to you too: https://github.com/briandotnet/AutoLayoutScrollViewExperiment